Is it possible to prefill the username in Keycloak Login via URL-parameter
I am currently working on a website where the users are authenticated by Keycloak.
The login has two different ways to login within one flow, because we have different types of users.
For this flow I first have username-form. According to the user who wants so login, whether a password form or a OTP form follows.
The system/website is sending e-mails to the clients in some cases. The mail contains a link to the system. I wonder, if I can add the username as parameter to the link (to Keycloak), to prefill or better skip the username form.
I searched the docs regarding URL-parameters. Even I couldn't find the documentation for the redirect_uri, which definitely exists.
The URL in the notification e-mail can/should look like this (username param at the end):
https://keycloak.mywebsite.com/auth/realms/myrealm/protocol/openid-connect/auth?client_id=myclient1&redirect_uri=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.mywebsite.com&username=foo.bar&...

Is there any possibility to achieve the desired behavior? Thank you in advance!
